# \textcolor is not working

Tags: color, undefined

I was trying to use a template where it has an environment named `rSection`. I wanted to use some color inside this environment. Here is the original definition:

```
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{% 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1 } % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{% List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}
```

I tried to change the color of the input argument by changing the line:

```
\MakeUppercase{\bf \textcolor{blue}{#1} }
```

But it is showing the following error:

> Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `BLUE'.

I have done some research and added the package `xcolor` with some arguments

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\PassOptionsToPackage{dvipsnames}{xcolor}
\RequirePackage{xcolor} % [dvipsnames] 
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55} % chapter numbers will be semi transparent .5 .55 .6 .0
\definecolor{webgreen}{rgb}{0,.5,0}
\definecolor{webbrown}{rgb}{.6,0,0}
%\definecolor{Maroon}{cmyk}{0, 0.87, 0.68, 0.32}
%\definecolor{RoyalBlue}{cmyk}{1, 0.50, 0, 0}
%\definecolor{Black}{cmyk}{0, 0, 0, 0}
```

And tried to use the colors `webgreen` or `webbrown`, but it still shows the same error.

Please let me know what can I do to solve this issue.

Comment: MakeUppercase uppercases also the color name. Put the text color command outside the uppercase command, or do \colorlet (BLUE}{blue}.

Comment: Off-topic: In a LaTeX document (as opposed to a Plain-TeX document), use `\bfseries` rather than `\bf`.

Comment: Great!, it solved the issue. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

The right way is

```
\textcolor{blue}{\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}
```

There's no point in having `\bf` (which should be `\bfseries`, for `\bf` has been obsolete and deprecated for 25 years) inside `\MakeUppercase` in the first place.

Also `\MakeUppercase{\bf #1 }` introduces an unwanted space; the fact that this space will be ignored because the line ends does not justify having it.

Separate formatting from processing: you want to color something that happens to be in boldface and is the uppercase version of the input.

Without color:

```
\textbf{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```